# Getting group by sum and total sum in a single query

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to get total price of all products by category and total price of all products in a single query.

Below is query i am using giving price by category.

```
SELECT SUM(price) as totalprice
FROM products 
Group BY category_id
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

use [ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) with your query.

The GROUP BY clause permits a WITH `ROLLUP` modifier that causes extra rows to be added to the summary output.

```
SELECT category_id,SUM(price) as totalprice
FROM products 
GROUP BY category_id WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 26):

```
SELECT category_id, SUM(price) as totalprice
FROM products 
GROUP BY category_id WITH ROLLUP
```

[MySQL Manual: GROUP BY Modifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

> The GROUP BY clause permits a WITH ROLLUP modifier that causes summary output to include extra rows that represent higher-level (that is, super-aggregate) summary operations. ROLLUP thus enables you to answer questions at multiple levels of analysis with a single query. For example, ROLLUP can be used to provide support for OLAP (Online Analytical Processing) operations.

Given the following sample data:

| id | name | category_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | prod_1 | 1 | 2.00 |
| 2 | prod_2 | 1 | 3.00 |
| 3 | prod_3 | 2 | 4.00 |
| 4 | prod_4 | 2 | 5.00 |
| 5 | prod_5 | 2 | 6.00 |

the above query will output:

| category_id | totalprice |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5.00 |
| 2 | 15.00 |
| NULL | 20.00 |

You can extend the above, using the [`GROUPING()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_grouping) function to distinguish `NULL` values in super-aggregate rows from those in regular grouped rows:

```
SELECT
    IF(GROUPING(category_id), 'All categories', category_id) AS category_id,
    SUM(price) as totalprice
FROM products 
GROUP BY category_id WITH ROLLUP
```

which will output:

| category_id | totalprice |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5.00 |
| 2 | 15.00 |
| All categories | 20.00 |

Comment: How do I get this into the same row?