# Sum up grouped values with MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following problem:

I have this query:

```
SELECT  DATE(timestamp) Date, COUNT(DISTINCT ipNum) as totalCount
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY  DATE(timestamp)
```

I get a result like this:

*Date            totalCount*

---

1.1.            7

---

2.1.            19

---

**I need just the sum of all totalCount values. Is this possible with MySql?**

I googled a lot ([Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894301/getting-group-by-sum-and-total-sum-in-a-single-query), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048887/mysql-group-by-and-sum-total-value-of-other-column), [Link3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68621/get-only-overall-summary-with-rollup-and-group-by-for-multiple-fields)) but nothing really answers my question.

I created a fiddle to illustrate my case: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4fd9/22

Comment: Why not just "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ipNum) as totalCount FROM    tableName"?

Comment: because i need it per day. i have an addidtional where for the date restriction. i left it out to clarify my point.

Comment: Why don't you add some sample data, and expected output...

Comment: that's why i put the fiddle ;)

Comment: But I still don't get what the expected result is?

Comment: that you get the total sum of all previously grouped numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use a derived table like this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ipNum) as amount, DATE(timestamp)
  FROM tableName 
  GROUP BY DATE(timestamp) 
) x
```