# Group by field doesn't work in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to calculate a sum of all records in my db, and I need to avoid duplicates. I wrote this code to group the records, but it doesn't work for me.

```
$pipeline = [
    ['$match' =>
            $criteria->getCondition()],
    ['$group' => 
            ['_id' => '$order_id', 'total' => ['$sum' => '$'.$column]]]
];

$this->getDbConnection()->aggregate('ticket_cache', $pipeline);
```

Test request:

```
db.getCollection('ticket_cache').aggregate(
{
"$match":
    {"event_id":64}
},
{
    "$group" : 
        {"_id":"$order_id", "total": {"$sum":"$payment_amount"}}
})
```

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(7002),
            "total" : 9000.0000000000000000
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Data in the db:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("553f8b4fbfabe2772f8b4f51"),
            "event_id" : NumberLong(64),
            "ticket_id" : NumberLong(8563),
            "ticket_code" : NumberLong(22062299),
            "ticket_type_id" : NumberLong(391),
            "ticket_created" : NumberLong(1430227620),
            "ticket_deleted" : NumberLong(0),
            "ticket_user_id" : NumberLong(2),
            "ticket_used" : NumberLong(0),
            "order_id" : NumberLong(7002),
            "order_code" : NumberLong(517005),
            "order_created" : NumberLong(1430227620),
            "order_deleted" : NumberLong(0),
            "order_sales_pipeline" : NumberLong(18),
            "order_invoice_id" : NumberLong(4202),
            "order_invoice_amount" : 3000.0000000000000000,
            "order_invoice_created" : NumberLong(1430227641),
            "order_invoice_deleted" : NumberLong(0),
            "order_invoice_code" : NumberLong(420155),
            "payment_id" : NumberLong(4365),
            "payment_amount" : 3000.0000000000000000,
            "payment_currency" : NumberLong(4),
            "payment_author_id" : NumberLong(1),
            "payment_type_id" : NumberLong(27),
            "payment_created" : NumberLong(1430227641),
            "payment_deleted" : NumberLong(0),
            "create_time" : ISODate("2015-04-28T13:29:51.328Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("553f8b4fbfabe2772f8b4f4f"),
            "event_id" : NumberLong(64),
            "ticket_id" : NumberLong(8561),
            "ticket_code" : NumberLong(49287433),
            "ticket_type_id" : NumberLong(391),
            "ticket_created" : NumberLong(1430227620),
            "ticket_deleted" : NumberLong(0),
            "ticket_user_id" : NumberLong(2),
            "ticket_used" : NumberLong(0),
            "order_id" : NumberLong(7002),
            "order_code" : NumberLong(517005),
            "order_created" : NumberLong(1430227620),
            "order_deleted" : NumberLong(0),
            "order_sales_pipeline" : NumberLong(18),
            "order_invoice_id" : NumberLong(4202),
            "order_invoice_amount" : 3000.0000000000000000,
            "order_invoice_created" : NumberLong(1430227641),
            "order_invoice_deleted" : NumberLong(0),
            "order_invoice_code" : NumberLong(420155),
            "payment_id" : NumberLong(4365),
            "payment_amount" : 3000.0000000000000000,
            "payment_currency" : NumberLong(4),
            "payment_author_id" : NumberLong(1),
            "payment_type_id" : NumberLong(27),
            "payment_created" : NumberLong(1430227641),
            "payment_deleted" : NumberLong(0),
            "create_time" : ISODate("2015-04-28T13:29:51.316Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("553f8b4fbfabe2772f8b4f50"),
            "event_id" : NumberLong(64),
            "ticket_id" : NumberLong(8562),
            "ticket_code" : NumberLong(24016753),
            "ticket_type_id" : NumberLong(391),
            "ticket_created" : NumberLong(1430227620),
            "ticket_deleted" : NumberLong(0),
            "ticket_user_id" : NumberLong(2),
            "ticket_used" : NumberLong(0),
            "order_id" : NumberLong(7002),
            "order_code" : NumberLong(517005),
            "order_created" : NumberLong(1430227620),
            "order_deleted" : NumberLong(0),
            "order_sales_pipeline" : NumberLong(18),
            "order_invoice_id" : NumberLong(4202),
            "order_invoice_amount" : 3000.0000000000000000,
            "order_invoice_created" : NumberLong(1430227641),
            "order_invoice_deleted" : NumberLong(0),
            "order_invoice_code" : NumberLong(420155),
            "payment_id" : NumberLong(4365),
            "payment_amount" : 3000.0000000000000000,
            "payment_currency" : NumberLong(4),
            "payment_author_id" : NumberLong(1),
            "payment_type_id" : NumberLong(27),
            "payment_created" : NumberLong(1430227641),
            "payment_deleted" : NumberLong(0),
            "create_time" : ISODate("2015-04-28T13:29:51.326Z")
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid duplicates"?  What are you expecting the result to look like?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, as you can see above, that I've got 3 records with same `order_id`. I need to calculate a sum of all records with "unique" `order_id`. In this case, I'm expecting to get '3000' because as I was saying before I've got records with same `order_id`, so after group it must find only one record (this case) and it should calculate the sum.

Comment: @Kossgreim - You can't calculate the sum of one number (well, you can; it's just the number). What you're asking Mongo to do is put everything with the same `order_id` into a group, then for each group, return the sum of each `payment_amount` in that group.

Comment: @xathien, example in SQL, it would give me the result I need: `SELECT SUM(payment_amount) as total FROM ticket_cache WHERE event_id = 64 GROUP BY order_id` it would return 3000

Comment: @Kossgreim - Well, no. That SQL query on your data would also return 9000, because it would put all 3 records into a group with `order_id = 7002`, then sum up the `payment_amount` field of all 3 records. What you want is to get the `payment_amount` of each group, and *then* sum.

Comment: @xathien. hmm, I haven't thought of that, I just tried, you're right. How would you correct the sql code in order to get 3000?

Comment: @Kossgreim - Two main ways. One is to use [ROLLUP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894301/getting-group-by-sum-and-total-sum-in-a-single-query) if you want the subtotals as well, or to use a subquery that gets RowIDs for the `DISTINCT order_id`, and then sums rows with those IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with the below query. It assumes that the payment amount will always be same. Have a look at addToSet http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/.

```
db.getCollection('ticket_cache').aggregate( 
{ "$match": {"event_id":64} }, 
{ "$group" :
     {"_id":"$order_id", "total": {"$addToSet":"$payment_amount"}}
},     
{"$unwind": "$total"}, 
{"$group": {"_id": "null", "totalOdr": {"$sum": "$total"}}}
)
```

Comment: The result is: 
`{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(7002),
            "totalOdr" : 3000.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(7003),
            "totalOdr" : 5000.0000000000000000
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}`

Comment: Is there a way to make it like this ? `
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(7002),
            "totalOdr" : 8000.0000000000000000
        }, 
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}` to sum all the results into one (in the case above it returns two: 3000 and 5000