# SQL Table Schema for Level -Sublevel Type Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I created four table that gives the hiearchical category list. Like  Categories table;

```
+----+--------------+---------------+----------------+
| ID | CategoryName | Ref. Category | Something else |
+----+--------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Ref. Category ( Link to column 1)

As an example;

```
+---+------------+---+------+
| 1 | Elektronik | 0 | ...  |
| 2 | Drink      | 0 | ...  |
| 3 | Computer   | 1 | ...  |
| 4 | Mouse      | 3 | ...  |
| 5 | Keyboard   | 3 | ...  |
| 6 | Juice      | 2 | ...  |
| 7 | Mouse Cable| 4 | ...  |
+---+------------+---+------+
```

Employees table:

```
+------------+------+---------+-----------+
| EmployeeID | Name | Surname | Something |
+------------+------+---------+-----------+
```

Orders table:

```
+---------+-------+------+-----------+
| OrderID | EmpID | Date | Something |
+---------+-------+------+-----------+
```

OrderDetails table:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+-------+------------+
| OrderID | ProductID | Quantity | Price | CategoryID |
+---------+-----------+----------+-------+------------+
```

I want to get the total prices of specific employees specific category  and above up levels (Ref. Categories up to 0 level) total prices as like
for EmployeeID 10

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+
| EmployeeID| CategoryId | CategoryName | Total Prices  |
| 10        |    7       | Mouse Cable  | 3000          |
| 10        |    4       | Mouse        | 5000          |
| 10        |    3       | Computer     | 12000         |
| 10        |    1       | Elektronik   | 35000         |
+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I want to create a query starts with specific RefID and then take CategoryID, In Next step, RefId will be CategoryID and continues like that up to RefID 0

Comment: Where is the query you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Elif A.   Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Please edit your question to include the query that you have developed so far, and what is wrong with the output that it produces.

Comment: I think you want to get categories total prices from starting CategoryID to level 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting group by sum and total sum in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894301/getting-group-by-sum-and-total-sum-in-a-single-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer will be long but below query works for you

```
DECLARE @rowResult TABLE (
    EmployeeID int,
    CategoryID int,
    Total int);
DECLARE @EmployeeID int;
DECLARE @CategoryID int;
DECLARE @RefID int;

SET @EmployeeID = 100;
SET @CategoryID = 7;

SELECT @RefID = RefID FROM CATEGORIES WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID;

WHILE @RefID > 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @rowResult
    SELECT e.EmployeeID, d.CategoryID, SUM(d.Quantity * d.Price) AS 'Total'
    FROM Employees e 
      INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.EmpID = e.EmployeeID
      INNER JOIN OrderDetails d ON d.OrderID = o.OrderID
    WHERE e.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND d.CategoryID = @CategoryID
    GROUP BY e.EmployeeID, d.CategoryID ;

    SET  @CategoryID = @RefID;
SELECT @RefID = RefID FROM CATEGORIES WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID;
END

SELECT * FROM @rowResult
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Runnnig code is below
http://rextester.com/VSNF73112

> > CATEGORIES

```
CREATE TABLE CATEGORIES (
  CategoryID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  CategoryName nvarchar(255),
  RefID int,
  Detail nvarchar(255)
);
```

> > EMPLOYEES

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
  EmployeeID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Name nvarchar(255),
  SurName nvarchar(255),
  Detail nvarchar(255)
);
```

> > OrderDetails

```
CREATE TABLE OrderDetails (
  OrderID int,
  ProductID int,
  Quantity int,
  Price int,
  CategoryID int
);
```

> > Orders

```
 CREATE TABLE Orders (
      OrderID int,
      EmpID int
    );

ALTER TABLE CATEGORIES
ADD FOREIGN KEY (RefID) REFERENCES CATEGORIES(CategoryID);
GO
```