# Mysql Select group by and without group by in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select group by and without group by in one select query? I have a query like this

```
SELECT date, sum(total) as quotation_total
  FROM suspended_bills 
 WHERE type='quotation'
 GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

Here it is taking a group by year and month but I want a sum(total) without group by year and month. So I am able to get full sum(total) without a division of month and year.

This is not a duplicate entry as rollup is generating extra rows that I dont need, I only need the total of sum, so when I run this query with rollup it gave me more rows that is not desired. So all is wrong with roll up query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting group by sum and total sum in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894301/getting-group-by-sum-and-total-sum-in-a-single-query)

Comment: For your information it is not a duplicate entry because by using your roll up I am getting only 5 results otherwise it should give me 8 results. I have seen the @Gordon solution that works perfect and giving me the exact result I want. So this is not a duplicate, If you need a reason then i can give you the proof.

Comment: Yes - I want to see it. Please create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: I am inserting the data but it is giving me error request entity too large because i have lots of data in my table

Comment: You only need some sample data (it doesn't need to be real data) - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, the easiest way is a `join` or subquery:

```
select YEAR(sb.date), MONTH(sb.date), sum(sb.total) as quotation_total,
       t.total_total
from suspended_bills sb cross join
      (select sum(total) as total_totla
       from suspended_bills
       where type = 'quotation'
      ) t
where sb.type = 'quotation'
group by YEAR(sb.date), MONTH(sb.date), t.total_total;
```