# How do I SUM a manually made column in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating a chart of accounts in mySql for a C# app that I am making for work. I manually got all of my data from my tables and named my columns. My problem is, How does one sum the debit column I made and then the credit column into a new row? Then sum the totals for the Grand Total.

I have tried the sum function but cant seem to make it work. I get the error unknown column 'Debit' in 'field list'

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1 as seq, '350' as Account, sum(invoice_amount) as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM invoice WHERE Voided = 0
    Union all
    SELECT 2 as seq, '103' as Account, 0 as Debit, sum(check_amount) as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM auctiondbh.Checks
    Union all
    SELECT 3 as seq, '356' as Account, 0 as Debit, sum(Amount) as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM ScratchBal WHERE rec_Owner = @PCName AND RowType = 'BFC'
    Union all
    SELECT 4 as seq, '554' as Account, 0 as Debit, sum(Amount) as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM ScratchBal WHERE rec_Owner = @PCName AND RowType = 'FEED' AND Description = 'Total Feed'
    Union all
    SELECT 5 as seq, '505' as Account, 0 as Debit, sum(Amount) as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM ScratchBal WHERE rec_Owner = @PCName AND RowType = 'TOT_COMM'
    Union all
    SELECT 6 as seq, '525' as Account, 0 as Debit, sum(Amount) as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM ScratchBal WHERE rec_Owner = @PCName AND RowType = 'CUSTOM_CHARGES' AND  description = 'Commingle%'
    Union all
    SELECT 7 as seq, '598' as Account, 0 as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total
    Union all
    SELECT 8 as seq, '362' as Account, sum(check_amount) as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM auctiondbh.Checks WHERE 'Comment' LIKE 'GEN. Trans%'
    Union all
    SELECT 9 as seq, '796' as Account, 0 as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total
    Union all
    SELECT 10 as seq, '366' as Account, sum(Amount) as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM ScratchBal WHERE rec_Owner = @PCName AND RowType = 'CUSTOM_CHARGES' and '%BUYER%'
    Union all
    SELECT 11 as seq, '368' as Account, 0 as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total
    Union all
    SELECT 12 as seq, '364' as Account, sum(check_amount) as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM auctiondbh.Checks where Comment like 'C/C%' 
    Union all
    SELECT 13 as seq, '999' as Account, sum(check_amount) as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM auctiondbh.Checks where Comment like 'DUP%'
        Union all
    SELECT 14 as seq, 'TOTALS' as Account, sum(Debit) as Debit, sum(Credit) as Credit, (sum(Debit) - Credit)  as total
) x
order by seq;
```

Heres how it should work:

```
seq --- Acct --- Debit   --  Credit --  Total  

1------ 350 -----    0  ------  0     
2------ 103 -----    10 ---- 10   
3------ 356 -----    3  ------  4     
4------ 554 -----    50 ---- 50   
5------ 505 -----    10 -----10   
...        
14--- TOTALS--- 73 --- 74 -----   (1)
```

line 14 will sum the debit and credit column, then sum the line 14 for grand total

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting group by sum and total sum in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894301/getting-group-by-sum-and-total-sum-in-a-single-query)

Comment: You show us how should look but don't give us the sample data. Is like you show me a cake and want me to reproduce it but without tell me what ingredients to use

Comment: No answer, but it may help the search. In the end it's not that different from selecting values from an actual table + its totals, so if you can write a query like `select Acct, Debit, Credit from ActualTable`, and can manage to have that query output the individual rows and the totals, you're there. The fact that this is a union of duals doesn't really matter.

Comment: And, to close in on the answer: I think by declaring a sub-query using `with`, you can reuse it. So you can have one subquery using values, and then you make a query that basically unions the subquery with the aggregated version of the subquery. That is, [if you're on MySQL 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)

Comment: But personally, I think I'd calculate the totals in C# or run two separate queries, and keep them simple. But that's a preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `With clause` to generate two queries from one

```
with cte0 as
(
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 1 as seq, '350' as Account, sum(invoice_amount) as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM invoice WHERE Voided = 0
        Union all
        SELECT 2 as seq, '103' as Account, 0 as Debit, sum(check_amount) as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM auctiondbh.Checks
        Union all
        SELECT 3 as seq, '356' as Account, 0 as Debit, sum(Amount) as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM ScratchBal WHERE rec_Owner = @PCName AND RowType = 'BFC'
        Union all
        SELECT 4 as seq, '554' as Account, 0 as Debit, sum(Amount) as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM ScratchBal WHERE rec_Owner = @PCName AND RowType = 'FEED' AND Description = 'Total Feed'
        Union all
        SELECT 5 as seq, '505' as Account, 0 as Debit, sum(Amount) as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM ScratchBal WHERE rec_Owner = @PCName AND RowType = 'TOT_COMM'
        Union all
        SELECT 6 as seq, '525' as Account, 0 as Debit, sum(Amount) as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM ScratchBal WHERE rec_Owner = @PCName AND RowType = 'CUSTOM_CHARGES' AND  description = 'Commingle%'
        Union all
        SELECT 7 as seq, '598' as Account, 0 as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total
        Union all
        SELECT 8 as seq, '362' as Account, sum(check_amount) as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM auctiondbh.Checks WHERE 'Comment' LIKE 'GEN. Trans%'
        Union all
        SELECT 9 as seq, '796' as Account, 0 as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total
        Union all
        SELECT 10 as seq, '366' as Account, sum(Amount) as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM ScratchBal WHERE rec_Owner = @PCName AND RowType = 'CUSTOM_CHARGES' and '%BUYER%'
        Union all
        SELECT 11 as seq, '368' as Account, 0 as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total
        Union all
        SELECT 12 as seq, '364' as Account, sum(check_amount) as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM auctiondbh.Checks where Comment like 'C/C%' 
        Union all
        SELECT 13 as seq, '999' as Account, sum(check_amount) as Debit, 0 as Credit, '  ' as Total FROM auctiondbh.Checks where Comment like 'DUP%'
    ) x
)
select * from cte0  union all
select max(seq) + 1, 'Totals', sum(debit), sum(credit), sum(debit) - sum(credit) from cte0
```

Comment: I think this is going to be the right way, although i'm getting an error when using the WITH at the beginning of the query. can you help me on this? @Simonare

Comment: the query is working for me. Can you please simulate error on https://dbfiddle.uk ?

Comment: Its giving the error "Unexpected WITH" Could this be because I'm using MySQL and you could be using Microsoft SQL server? @simonare